# Why aren't all of my TestMethods shown in the Test list with Unit Testing in VS2008?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2008

I have a Unit Testing Project that contains 4 .cpp files that each contain one [TestClass] with several [TestMethod]s. I'm using the built-in Unit Testing framework in Visual Studio 2008.

The problem is that the 7 tests defined in one of the .cpp files are not showing up at all in the Test Results window. The other three files are fine.

This was working fine just the other day and I'm not sure what I did to break it. I've done some Googling but haven't come across anything related to this specific problem. I've done a rebuild of the project and closing/reopening Visual Studio to no avail.

Has anyone ever ran into this problem? If so, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it worked, but I selected one of the TestMethods in the offending .cpp files, then went to Test -> Debug -> Tests in Current Context. The test then ran and showed up in the TestResults window.

The next time I tried to run all tests (through Debug -> Start Debugging (F5)), all tests from the offending .cpp file showed up in TestResults.

Comment: And now it's broken again but this workaround isn't working! Arrgh!